# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement chatbot_demo_rest (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for

Tags: python, package

I am a beginner in python and I currently struggle with the installation of 2 packages, namely `chatbot_demo_rest` and `RDPTokenManagement` (from `rdp_token`).
I tried to use pip install but I got the following errors:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement chatbot_demo_rest (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for chatbot_demo_rest.

I saw some topics on subjects that seems similar but I could not understand how to solve the issue. I
would be very thankful if you could answer with simple terms

best regards

Answer (score 0):

I can't find that project (`chatbot_demo_rest`) on [pypi.org](https://pypi.org) (where the packages are installed by default). Also, `pip` checks for the version classifiers, maybe your Python version is not supported.

Check the project name, and see if your Python version is supported.